# Unable to use the Request Body from POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm trying to develop api with node.js express api for my angular web front end.This **code worked when I used the params (http://localhost:5000/login/admin/00606006350066500673 ).**

But I don't know why **I'm getting an error while using the Request raw body data ({ strUserID: "admin" , strUserPwd: "00606006350066500673"})**

```
 router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
      let User = {
            strUserID : req.body.strUserID,
            strUserPwd : req.body.strUserPwd };

       function getUserPwd(strUID){
               var sqlConfig = {
                    user: 'sa',
                    password: 'XXXXX',
                    server: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com', 
                    database: 'XXXXX' 
                 };

             sql.connect(sqlConfig, function () {
                  var request = new sql.Request();
                  var strquery = "select fUserPwd from tblUser where fUserID ='"+User.strUserID+"'" 
                    request.query(strquery, function (err, recordset) {

                      return(recordset);
                     });
                     sql.close();
                });
        }

       if ( User.strUserPwd == getUserPwd(User.strUserID)) {
             let token = jwt.sign(User, global.config.secretKey, {
                algorithm: global.config.algorithm,
                expiresIn: '15m'
               });
             console.log("Token Generated :  "+  token + User );

             res.status(200).json({
                 token , User
               });
          }
        else {
          res.status(401).json({
          message: 'Login Failed'
         });
        } 
});
```

Comment: Well what error are you getting?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine fUserID is not defined... which is what I get after sql request.

Comment: Do you have a bodyParser middleware?

Comment: Then it looks like you are erroring out at the sql level. Run this code in debug mode, call the endpoint with the same data that caused it to throw an error, copy the actual query that gets built (the value of `strquery`), and run the query directly against sql. If you inspect the value of `strquery` you will probably find the issue.

Comment: seems that the column `fUserID` does not exist in the `tblUser` table

Comment: It exists... I have successfully developed an ERP solution using .NET

Comment: @SLaks no I have not included it

Comment: @NaseefAli your query is getting jacked up dude, inspect its value in debug mode.

Comment: Also its probably a lot better if you used pooled sql connection, instead of making a connection every time someone hits that endpoint. You should also store config in its own file.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Let me check and will update the results.